# React Webcam with Custom Hook

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm have an issue when combined react-webcam component with custom hook to interval the take photo.

**Case 1**: The first time take a picture, when the countdown timer / remaining time reaches 0, it doesn't immediately produce a photo, but have delay 1-2 seconds. and, taking the second picture and so on, it runs normally, when the countdown timer / remaining time reaches 0, it immediately produces images without a delay of 1-2 seconds.

**Case 2**: I also had an issue, when the picture had been taken 4 times, I still can runs the function of taking pictures.

I have tried case 1 and case 2 but it didn't work.

My hope is that the first time take a picture, when the countdown timer / remaining time reaches 0 it will immediately produce an image, without delay. Secondly, when there were 4 shots taken, I didn't want to do anything, but didn't want to carry out the picture taking function.

Example code below:

**useWebcam.js**

```js
import { useRef, useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';

export const constraints = {
    audio: false,
    video: true,
};

export const useWebcam = () => {
    const webcamRef = useRef(null);
    const captureCount = useRef(0);
    const [stream, setStream] = useState(null);
    const [screenshots, setScreenshots] = useState([]);
    const [isCapturing, setIsCapturing] = useState(false);
    const [remainingTime, setRemainingTime] = useState(3); // Capture every 3 seconds
    let intervalId;

    const startStream = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
            const userStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
            setStream(userStream);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }, []);

    const capturePhoto = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
            if (!stream || !isCapturing || captureCount.current === 4) return;

            const track = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
            const imageCapture = new ImageCapture(track);
            const blob = await imageCapture.takePhoto();

            setScreenshots((prevState) => [...prevState, blob]);
            captureCount.current += 1;
            setRemainingTime(3); // Reset the timer

            // Automatically stop capturing after taking a photo
            setIsCapturing(false);

            if (captureCount.current === 4) {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }, [stream, isCapturing, captureCount]);

    useEffect(() => {
        startStream();

        return () => {
            if (stream) {
                stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
            }
        };
    }, [startStream]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (stream !== null && isCapturing && captureCount.current < 4) {
            if (remainingTime <= 0) {
                capturePhoto();
            }

            intervalId = setInterval(() => {
                if (remainingTime <= 0) {
                    capturePhoto();
                } else {
                    setRemainingTime((prevRemainingTime) => prevRemainingTime - 1);
                }
            }, 1000);

            return () => {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
            };
        }
    }, [stream, isCapturing, remainingTime]);

    const startCapture = () => {
        setIsCapturing(true);
    };

    return {
        screenshots,
        webcamRef,
        isCapturing,
        startCapture,
        remainingTime,
    };
};
```

**Webcam.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import Webcam from 'react-webcam';

import { constraints, useWebcam } from '@shared/hooks/useWebcam/useWebcam';


const Page = () => {
    const { screenshots, webcamRef, isCapturing, startCapture, remainingTime } = useWebcam();

    console.log(screenshots, 'screenshots');

    return (
        <React.Fragment>

            {screenshots.length < 4 && (
                <Webcam
                    audio={false}
                    height={720}
                    ref={webcamRef}
                    screenshotFormat='image/png'
                    width={1280}
                    videoConstraints={constraints}
                />
            )}

            {isCapturing ? (
                <div>
                    <p>Capturing ({remainingTime} seconds)</p>
                </div>
            ) : (
                <button onClick={startCapture}>Start Capture</button>
            )}

            <div className='screenshots'>
                {screenshots.map((blob, index) => (
                    <img key={index} src={URL.createObjectURL(blob)} alt={`Screenshot ${index}`} />
                ))}
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

Page.getLayout = function getLayout(page) {
    return <BaseLayout pageProps={undefined}>{page}</BaseLayout>;
};

export default Page;
```

I need your help to suggest how to solve this issue?